# Running go run main.go in cloud shell without deploying app engine, returning errors

Tags: shell, go, google-app-engine, cloud, gcloud

I am deploying a REST API using app engine

When I use gcloud app deploy, the API works perfectly fine. However, I want to be able to test my go code without deploying by using

```
go run main.go
```

however, I get this error when I run it

```
panic: Metadata fetch failed for 'instance/attributes/gae_backend_version': metadata server returned HTTP 404

goroutine 66 [running]:
google.golang.org/appengine/internal.mustGetMetadata(0xac3a19, 0x27, 0x0, 0x0, 0x1d)
        /google/gopath/src/google.golang.org/appengine/internal/metadata.go:34 +0x148
google.golang.org/appengine/internal.VersionID(0x0, 0x0, 0xaaafac, 0x1)
        /google/gopath/src/google.golang.org/appengine/internal/identity_vm.go:91 +0x100
google.golang.org/appengine/internal.DefaultTicket.func1()
        /google/gopath/src/google.golang.org/appengine/internal/api.go:299 +0x13f
sync.(*Once).doSlow(0xffb060, 0xad9bb8)
        /usr/local/go/src/sync/once.go:66 +0xe3
sync.(*Once).Do(...)
        /usr/local/go/src/sync/once.go:57
google.golang.org/appengine/internal.DefaultTicket(0xc0002c8240, 0x971640)
        /google/gopath/src/google.golang.org/appengine/internal/api.go:292 +0x65
google.golang.org/appengine/internal.Call(0xb80880, 0xc0002c8240, 0xab04b5, 0xa, 0xaabd4e, 0x5, 0xb7c080, 0xc00028a1c0, 0xb7b280, 0xc00044e080, ...)
        /google/gopath/src/google.golang.org/appengine/internal/api.go:499 +0x907
google.golang.org/appengine/internal.(*context).flushLog(0xc0002502a0, 0x1, 0x0)
        /google/gopath/src/google.golang.org/appengine/internal/api.go:644 +0x419
google.golang.org/appengine/internal.handleHTTP.func1(0xc000468180, 0xc0002502a0)
        /google/gopath/src/google.golang.org/appengine/internal/api.go:141 +0x60
created by google.golang.org/appengine/internal.handleHTTP
        /google/gopath/src/google.golang.org/appengine/internal/api.go:137 +0x38c
exit status 2
```

This link
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-go/Fd8DxpzEoVs
says to add appengine.Main() to my main func which is already added

Comment: What version of Go are you running? Can you add some reproducible code to your question?

Comment: my version is go version go1.13 linux/amd64
good point, the code has some sesitive info, so i'll see if i can try and create a simple API

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem? I encountered a similar issue and has not found a solution.

Comment: yes i used the dev app server. Might be this link https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-local-server but i can try to post a full response